# AWS rds proxy not releasing connection to db

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-rds-proxy

I have setup a rds proxy in between my webapp and rds mysql. However, when my webapp releases connection, rds proxy keep holding it. What is the parameter that decide the time that rds proxy release the connection to db? I provided 2 images, the first one show connections from webapp, and the second one show connections from rds rpoxy to db.

[onnections from webapp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ctYFQ.png)

[connections from rds rpoxy to db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KWfZY.png)

Comment: There is a parameter - Idle client connection timeout - in RDS Proxy settings.

Comment: did you resolve this?

Comment: the same happens for my scenario, even though the Idle client connection timeout is set to one minute in proxy, the db connections are not released, but interestingly my client connections are released and falls to zero. in my case I'm invoking through lambda @ElenaSharovar